# Use regexp to find typos

Tags: regex, filter

I'm looking for typos in my code, using Qt Creator's regexp-based search.

For instance, I'd like to find the cases where somebody types `fnuction`, or `fucntion` instead of the correct `function`.

I have this regexp: `[functio]{8}` which will find all combinations of the letters contained in function, of length 8.

NOW, I'd like to filter out the results where `function` is written correctly.

How do I do that?

Comment: I am afraid you can't do that with a regex-only approach. I'm curious to see what answers you will get :)

Comment: As my cousin BlackBear said, this can't be done with regexes only. Just use that regex and then filter out exact matches for "function".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using negative-lookaheads:

```
(?!function)[functio]{8}
```

But you will need a full dictionary and it may become quite complicated.
However, I think this should work for this isolated case - you might be able to scale it up to be more useful for your purposes.

Comment: It's a start but `ffffffff` would be considered a typo too.

Comment: @Birei yes, true... and there may be more than 1 8-letter word that contains an f at all... and then it wouldn't know which one to chose. You are right. That just means that  `[functio]{8}` is a hopeless effort - but it really all depends on the context that OP has. We'll let them clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Use fuzzy matching approach, either fuzzy support in your regex engine or entire fuzzy regex engine.

for example [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module support it.